# How to fix this code, trying to click button

Tags: applescript

Trying to click the button "Choose" but no success. I have a ​code below trying to correct.

[image]

Tried this code, but giving me an error.

```
error "System Events got an error: Can’t get process \"safari\"." number -1728 from process "safari"

'''activate application "Safari"
tell application "System Events" to tell process "safari"
    click button "choose" of sheet 1 of window 1
end tell
'''
```

here is the code I want to correct

```
'''button "Choose" of sheet 1 of window 1 of application process "Safari" of application "System Events"
'''
```

Comment: activate application "Safari"
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
 click button "choose" of sheet 1 of window 1
end tell

Comment: Hint: Case sensitivity matters.

Comment: Different Hint: the button is highlighted blue.

Answer (score 0):

I always find it clearer to nest tell blocks; it makes debugging easier, because you can throw in `log` statements or other checks at different levels. So I'd use this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        set frontmost to true
        tell window 1
            tell sheet 1
                click button "Choose"
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Remember, System Events is picky and case-sensitive. It will find `process "Safari"` but throw a fit over `process "safari"`; indexes of objects might change without notice if things are at all dynamic; you might have to hunt through the structure to find what you want. For instance, I'll often throw in a line like `properties of every button` at one level or another in the code just to see what shows up in the Script Editor's logs, and what the best way to identify what I want might be.